# What Jaspersoft's Alternatives do i have with mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, jasper-reports, reporting

I need to report on the mongoDB data fast. Jaspersoft seems ok but what other alternative do i have ?

Thanks

Comment: You can try BIRT - http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other big BI suite that supports MongoDB is Pentaho. This was [announced *very* recently](http://www.marketwatch.com/story/pentaho-open-sources-big-data-capabilities-to-further-fuel-widespread-adoption-2012-01-30).

From a big picture perspective, there is very little specific tooling around MongoDB reporting. I have yet to see anything like the typical drag and drop UIs available in the SQL world.

You typically end up pulling out the data in code and passing the "array of data" to whatever reporting tool you use.

Note that aggregation in MongoDB typically requires Map / Reduce. If you're looking to do queries with `SUM` or `AVG`, you are likely going to write code around this.

Comment: The Pentaho announcement seems to be around ETL only, no? If so, then it's not really parallel to the Jaspersoft MongoDB connector that runs find queries and map reduce jobs from the report engine.

Comment: Yes if Pentaho does not support MapReduce then Jaspersoft is better

Comment: Actually, I wasn't trying to say Jaspersoft is better... just that supporting MongoDB in an ETL tool is different.

Answer (score 0):

JReport by Jinfonet Software also connects directly to MongoDB's API without writing any code. Simply point JReport Designer to the MongoDB collection and JReport builds a meta-data layer that maps the data to look like relational tables to easily build reports and do analysis.  Here is a post with more  information[1](http://blog.jinfonet.com/mongodb-reporting-visualization-jreport/)